# Unable to locate valid Java version on Cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin

Whenever I run the following application from Cygwin, I get the following error message.

```
esrikom@US-00006401 /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/ltng-R232F/ltng/bin
$ ./ltng-decoder
The system cannot find the path specified.

ERROR: Unable to locate valid Java version (1.8 or later required)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Cygwin package for Java.

You can try with a Windows version of the package but you need to pass windows path to it, using cygpath.

```
$ cygpath --help
Usage: cygpath (-d|-m|-u|-w|-t TYPE) [-f FILE] [OPTION]... NAME...
       cygpath [-c HANDLE]
       cygpath [-ADHOPSW]
       cygpath [-F ID]

Convert Unix and Windows format paths, or output system path information

Output type options:

  -d, --dos             print DOS (short) form of NAMEs (C:\PROGRA~1\)
  -m, --mixed           like --windows, but with regular slashes (C:/WINNT)
  -M, --mode            report on mode of file (binmode or textmode)
  -u, --unix            (default) print Unix form of NAMEs (/cygdrive/c/winnt)
  -w, --windows         print Windows form of NAMEs (C:\WINNT)
  ....
```